# pygame.examples.aliens not working (syntax error)

Tags: python, pygame

If i try to run the example code "python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens" i get a syntax error (see code bellow). I thought that i didn't install pygame correctly but i don't get an error when i type import pygame. So i think it should be installed and working.

```
import pygame
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: are you running the "python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens" inside the python interpeter or on your terminal?

Comment: the python interpeter

Comment: Ahh, ok ill awnser what's the problem in the awnsers

Answer (score 0):

From what i see the problem is that you're actualy suposed to run the command in your terminal and not in the python intrepeter. So just open a new terminal and type the command there

Comment: If you got any more question, just reply to me in the comments here

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem until I closed the terminal and opened a new one lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31406448)